Batch loading for Firebase in SwiftUI
Does anyone know how to fetch only like 5 posts at a time? Like when you're scrolling though the ScrollView { I want only the posts that should be seen being loaded in. I need to reduce the amount of network requests and optimize for lag. I tried so many things and it hasn't been working.
func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping (Result<[PostWithUser], Error>) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if !self.cachedPosts.isEmpty {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(self.cachedPosts))
                }
                return
            }

            self.postsRef.order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                    return
                }

                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.success([]))
                    }
                    return
                }

                let group = DispatchGroup()
                var postsWithUsers: [PostWithUser] = []

                for document in documents {
                    group.enter()
                    let data = document.data()

                    guard let userId = data["userId"] as? String,
                          let parentId = data["parentId"] as? String,
                          let groupId = data["groupId"] as? String,
                          let text = data["text"] as? String,
                          let isPinned = data["isPinned"] as? Bool,
                          let imageUrl = data["imageUrl"] as? String,
                          let videoUrl = data["videoUrl"] as? String,
                          let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp,
                          let views = data["views"] as? Int else {
                        group.leave()
                        continue
                    }

                    let post = Post(id: document.documentID, userId: userId, parentId: parentId, groupId: groupId, text: text, imageUrl: imageUrl, videoUrl: videoUrl, timestamp: timestamp.dateValue(), isPinned: isPinned, likedBy: [], views: views)

                    self.usersRef.document(userId).getDocument { userDocument, error in
                        defer { group.leave() }

                        if let userDocument = userDocument, let userData = userDocument.data() {
                            let user = User(
                                id: userId,
                                username: userData["username"] as? String ?? "",
                                bio: userData["bio"] as? String ?? "",
                                profilePictureUrl: userData["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? "",
                                privateProfile: userData["privateProfile"] as? Bool ?? false,
                                privateFollowerList: userData["privateFollowerList"] as? Bool ?? false,
                                privateFollowingList: userData["privateFollowingList"] as? Bool ?? false,
                                privateReplies: userData["privateReplies"] as? Bool ?? false,
                                privateLikes: userData["privateLikes"] as? Bool ?? false,
                                accountDeactivated: userData["accountDeactivated"] as? Bool ?? false
                            )
                            let postWithUser = PostWithUser(post: post, user: user)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                postsWithUsers.append(postWithUser)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to fetch user data for userId: \(userId), error: \(String(describing: error))")
                        }
                    }
                }

                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                    self.cachedPosts = postsWithUsers
                    completion(.success(postsWithUsers))
                }
            }
        }
    }

I used a .lazy for ForEach { and I also tried a LazyVStack { but does not work.

Look up paging in the documentation

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors
